# Cuda GPU is slower than CPU in simple numpy operation

Tags: python, numpy, cuda, nvidia

I am using this code based on [this article](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/numba-python-cuda-acceleration/) to see the GPU accelerations, but all I can see is slowdown:

```
import numpy as np
from timeit import default_timer as timer
from numba import vectorize
import sys

if len(sys.argv) != 3:
    exit("Usage: " + sys.argv[0] + " [cuda|cpu] N(100000-11500000)")


@vectorize(["float32(float32, float32)"], target=sys.argv[1])
def VectorAdd(a, b):
    return a + b

def main():
    N = int(sys.argv[2])
    A = np.ones(N, dtype=np.float32)
    B = np.ones(N, dtype=np.float32)

    start = timer()
    C = VectorAdd(A, B)
    elapsed_time = timer() - start
    #print("C[:5] = " + str(C[:5]))
    #print("C[-5:] = " + str(C[-5:]))
    print("Time: {}".format(elapsed_time))

main()
```

The results:

```
$ python speed.py cpu 100000
Time: 0.0001056949986377731
$ python speed.py cuda 100000
Time: 0.11871792199963238

$ python speed.py cpu 11500000
Time: 0.013704434997634962
$ python speed.py cuda 11500000
Time: 0.47120747699955245
```

I cannot send bigger vector as that will generate a `numba.cuda.cudadrv.driver.CudaAPIError: Call to cuLaunchKernel results in CUDA_ERROR_INVALID_VALUE` exception.`

The output of `nvidia-smi` is

```
Fri Dec  8 10:36:19 2017
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 384.98                 Driver Version: 384.98                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Quadro 2000D        Off  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 30%   36C   P12    N/A /  N/A |    184MiB /   959MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0       933      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            94MiB |
|    0       985      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                          86MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Details of the CPU

```
$ lscpu
Architecture:        x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
CPU(s):              4
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-3
Thread(s) per core:  1
Core(s) per socket:  4
Socket(s):           1
NUMA node(s):        1
Vendor ID:           GenuineIntel
CPU family:          6
Model:               58
Model name:          Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3550 CPU @ 3.30GHz
Stepping:            9
CPU MHz:             3300.135
CPU max MHz:         3700.0000
CPU min MHz:         1600.0000
BogoMIPS:            6600.27
Virtualization:      VT-x
L1d cache:           32K
L1i cache:           32K
L2 cache:            256K
L3 cache:            6144K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):   0-3
Flags:               fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm cpuid_fault epb tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase smep erms xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts
```

The GPU is Nvidia Quadro 2000D with 192 CUDA cores and 1Gb RAM.

More complex operation:

```
import numpy as np
from timeit import default_timer as timer
from numba import vectorize
import sys

if len(sys.argv) != 3:
    exit("Usage: " + sys.argv[0] + " [cuda|cpu] N()")


@vectorize(["float32(float32, float32)"], target=sys.argv[1])
def VectorAdd(a, b):
    return a * b

def main():
    N = int(sys.argv[2])
    A = np.zeros((N, N), dtype='f')
    B = np.zeros((N, N), dtype='f')
    A[:] = np.random.randn(*A.shape)
    B[:] = np.random.randn(*B.shape)

    start = timer()
    C = VectorAdd(A, B)
    elapsed_time = timer() - start
    print("Time: {}".format(elapsed_time))

main()
```

Results:

```
$ python complex.py cpu 3000
Time: 0.010573603001830634
$ python complex.py cuda 3000
Time: 0.3956961739968392
$ python complex.py cpu 30
Time: 9.693001629784703e-06
$ python complex.py cuda 30
Time: 0.10848476299725007
```

Any idea why?

Comment: You are currently paying the cost of moving to the GPU which is very slow compared to a CPU with an L1, L2 cache. To fully leverage the power of the GPU you want to send over bigger chunks to the GPU.

Comment: Even with array a 100 times bigger the CPU is still faster, though the relative speed is much smaller.

Comment: The only problem here is your unrealistic performance expectations. Your example is completely memory and latency bound and you are running on a *very* modest GPU. You would maybe 6 to 10 orders of magnitude more floating point operations to see useful speed up

Comment: @talonmies that might be the case, but you see that example seemed to be the one Nvidia used. Would you care suggesting an example that will show the speed improvement? Would multiple matrix operations inside the VectorAdd function matter?

Comment: @szabgab Did Nvidia claim on performance improvement on matrix addition example? Again the GPU config would matter here as commented earlier. You could increase the compute/memory ratio with reduction operations, trigonometrical ones, etc.

Comment: @szabgab: I think you should re-read that blog post you are citing. At any stage was it claimed that the example in question yielded performance improvements compared to vanilla Python? It isn't my job to provide you with performance testing examples. You asked what is wrong, and the simple answer is nothing,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Despite the example being on the web site of Nvidia used to show "how to use the GPU", plain matrix addition will be probably slower using GPU that using the CPU. Primarily due to the overhead of copying over the data to the GPU.

Even simple math calculations might be slower. Heavier computations can already show the gain. I've put my results together in an article [showing speed improvement with GPU, cuda, and numpy](https://code-maven.com/showing-speed-improvement-with-gpu-cuda-numpy)

In a nutshell the question was which is bigger

CPU time

or

copy to GPU + GPU time + copy from GPU

Answer (score 8):

Probably your array is too small and the operation too simple to offset the cost of data transfer associated to the GPU. Other way to see it, is that you're not being fair in your timing since for the GPU it also is timing the memory transfer time and not only the processing time.

Try some more challenging example, maybe first an element wise big matrix multiplication and then a matrix multiplication.

In the end, the power of the GPU is to perform many operations on the same data so you end up paying only once the data transfer cost.

Comment: Increasing the array would just increase the transfer time. So I think I need a more complex operation, right? See my update.

Comment: Yes, maybe just adding longer vectors will not offset the transfer. But if you apply a trigonometric function or other operations as already suggested in other comments, and do the outer product and chain operations, you should see an improvement.

Comment: I tried np.sin(a) It worked using the cpu, but I got an error  "numba.errors.UntypedAttributeError: Failed at nopython (nopython frontend) Unknown attribute 'sin' of type Module" when using cuda.

Comment: Use the `sin` from the `math` standard library. `numba` knows how to work with arrays for transfering data, but its magic operates on normal python functions. You should take a look to this notebook https://github.com/ContinuumIO/gtc2017-numba/blob/master/2%20-%20CUDA%20Basics.ipynb Also, check the rest of that repository. It's a decent introduction to `numba`.

Comment: It was in the article you linked in your first sentence ;) I just remembered that I went through it some time ago.

Comment: I have put together my conclusions here: https://code-maven.com/showing-speed-improvement-with-gpu-cuda-numpy thank you for you help.